# Session.get does not set variable in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

`fruit` is a variable that is shared between template helpers `Template.fruits.name` and `Template.fruits.nick` to prevent duplicating code in each individual helper function.

However when the `change #fruit-selector` event handler is triggered, the shared variable `fruit` does not change even though its set by `Session.get('fruit')`.

Does this mean I cannot use this approach of declaring `fruit` variable as shown if I want it to be reactive?

**main.js**

```
(function() {

    // Set default fruit
    if(!Session.get('fruit')) {
        Session.set('fruit', 'apple');
    }

    var fruit = Session.get('fruit');


    Template.fruits.name = function() {
        return fruit;
    };

    Template.fruits.nickname = function() {
        return fruit + 'y';
    };

    Template.fruits.name2 = function() {
        return Session.get('fruit');
    };


    Template.fruits.events({
        'change #fruit-selector': function(e) {
            Session.set('fruit', e.target.value);
            console.log('fruit: ' + fruit)
        }
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Session.get('fruit')` inside the template helpers, otherwise they won't respond to the changes (`fruit` is not a reactive data source, it has got it value from a reactive data source).

PS
Use `Session.setDefault('fruit', 'apple')`, instead of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (did you mean Template.fruit.nickname or Template.fruits.nickname?):

```
(function() {

    // Set default fruit
    if(!Session.get('fruit')) {
        Session.set('fruit', 'apple');
    }

    Template.fruits.name = function() {
        return Session.get('fruit');
    };

    Template.fruit.nickname = function() {
        return Session.get('fruit') + 'y';
    };

    Template.fruits.name2 = function() {
        return Session.get('fruit');
    };


    Template.fruits.events({
        'change #fruit-selector': function(e) {
            Session.set('fruit', e.target.value);
            console.log('fruit: ' + Session.get('fruit'))
        }
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, session is no longer part of the default meteor package. 
Go to command prompt and run "meteor add session"